# Привязка ActiveX элемента к ячейке при дублировании

Tags: excel, vba, office, activex

Есть лист, на нем в одной из ячеек сделал выпадающий список ActiveX, выводящий выбор в ячейку C2.
Мне нужно, чтобы во всех ячейках столбца С (кроме первого - заголовок) был этот элемент выпадающего списка.

Т.е. заношу в таблицу новую запись и в столбце С выбираю значение списка (Да/Нет)
Сейчас при дублировании ячейки С2, вносится лишь значение ячейки, т.е. сам элемент к ней никак не привязан. Как я понял, необходимо написать скрипт на VBA, прошу помощи, хотя бы направить, в какую сторону копать.

(Пробовал дублировать ячейку в режиме конструктора, дублируются и элементы, как и нужно, но выпадающий список по прежнему привязывает вывод в C2, а не в C3, C4, C5 и т.д.)

[image: Пытаюсь дублировать]

[image: Получаю это]

[image: А надо получить это]

Comment: Скрин 1 - пытаюсь дублировать
Скрин 2 - то, что получаю
Скрин 3 - то, что нужно получить

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос ни о чем оказался.
Я новичок в Excel, достаточно было сделать просто список через "Проверку данных".

Comment: ...для целого столбца